# Post Request from axios always returns Unauthorized despite having valid JWT set in header/Axios Deletes Headers

Tags: reactjs, express, axios, jwt, passport-jwt

I set up passport-local to login a user, and then once logged in, the user will be given a JWT token through passport-JWT. The JWTStrategy is set up to use
`jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken()` so that the JWT can sent with the Authorization header `` Authorization: `Token ${userContext.token}`} ``. In my react client side, I have set up a `GET` request using axios as shown here:

```
const fetchProfileDetails = async(config)=>{
    const res = await axios.get("http://localhost:8080/users/me", config)
}

    const config = {
        method:"GET",
        withCredentials: true,
        headers: {Authorization: `Bearer ${userContext.token}`}
    }
```

This request successfully authenticates and returns the user data from /me.

Now heres the kicker: when I use the exact same request structure, but switch the method to post in the axios request and in my express route in the backend, the request always responds with a `401 Unauthorized`.

However, when I send the same request from POSTMAN, with the same Bearer Token used in the request that was Unauthorized, the request succeeds without any errors.

TLDR: GET requests work with the JWT token and return with a 200 status code, while the same request with a POST method returns with a 401 status code.

What am I missing here??!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have come upon a solution for this issue. For some reason, axios was not maintaining the Authorization header I had set in my config variable, and deleted it upon making the request. To solve this, I just had to reshuffle my axios request to look like this:

```
const res = await axios({
    method:'POST',
    url:"http://localhost:8080/users/test",
    headers:{'Authorization':`Bearer${token}`
  
  }})
```

I feel cheated as I spent a ton of time on this and the solution was so underwhelming. Axios was trolling me the whole time :/

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using there `GET` and not using `POST` anywhere.
In your code, you have code only for `get`. You will need to write code for `post` as well.
Below is the code for `post` for your reference:

```
router.post('/', config, async(req, res, next) => { 
    const { error } = validateBody(req.body);

    if (error) {
        return res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message);
    }    
    const newData= new passport({ name: req.body.name });    
    await newData.save();
    console.log('saving the document');
    res.send(newData);
})
```

Your code should have `post` as well. Writing single code will not work. You need to have to write code for every condition and every possibility. So like for `get` need code for `post` as well, also if you have condition for `patch` or `delete` or `put` you will have to write the axios method for that as well.

Hope this has helped you in any way.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have both a get and a post route set up on the server to handle each type of request. So this is not the issue.